# All git commands outside a repository fail

Tags: git

I created one git repo on my machine (Linux Mint 17) a week back and it worked fine. (I also cloned several while setting up my desktop.) Yesterday, I went to clone another repository, and all I get is a terribly cryptic error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Experimenting with other git commands yields the same error message: `git init`, `git clone`, `git help`, git, etc.

I can use git commands in that first repository, but anything outside the repo fails. I have disabled the git plugin for zsh and checked that I don't have any GIT* environment variables.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you in the right folder? Do you see a `.git`? (`ls -al`)

Comment: I said in the post that the real problem is when I am trying to _create_ a new git repo. I can not clone or init a new repo or run any git command outside of the first repository. There are no .git files anywhere other than in that first repo.

Comment: when outside the directory, where everything works. Does `git init` yield `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`? I need to confirm that part, cause that would be weird.

Comment: Hah sorry. It sounds like I'm not articulating myself correctly. Everything I do _inside_ the repository works. Anything I do _outside_ does not. I can't, for example, run "git init" or "git clone".

Comment: Er sorry. "git --help" works outside the repo. "git help", which returns something like status when in the existing repo, does not.

Comment: Also for reference, I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling git with apt.

Comment: Found it. I had an entry "git="git status"" in my zshrc for some reason. I'm going to track back through the packages I installed to see if one of those is at fault. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bad entry in my `.zshrc` file:

```
alias git="git status"
```

This completely broke git.